# Datatype of list - moscow ml

Tags: ml

I would like to do representation of list of katalogs and list of books.

```
datatype catalog = KAT of string*catalog list| KIS of string*book list | EMPTY;
```

and I would like to count the books. I am trying to do something like this.

```
fun count([]) = 0
  | count(book) = LIST.length(book)
  | count(x1::xs) = count(x1) + count(xs);`
```

and I receive cannot have type error. What can I do to caunt books ?

Comment: What is the definition of `book`?

Comment: `type book = string*string;`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to be more careful with the definition of functions. For example, it seems that you want to count all the books and the catalogs inside with the same function. This is not possible in ML, because although you can include several instances of the function for pattern matching, the matching has to be done over just one type.

For example, in your code, it seems that you want to use `count()` for counting either given a catalog or a list of books or catalogs. This can be done, but it is not the usual way in ML. You have to write a function to count all the catalogs in the catalog list of type `catalog`, *and* another function to count the books and catalogs. The length function works as expected, so the following function may work:

```
fun countcatalogs ([]) = 0 
    | countcatalogs(cat::rest) = countbooks(cat) + countcatalogs(rest)
and
    countbooks (EMPTY) = 0  
    | countbooks (KIS(_, l)) = length(l) 
    | countbooks (KAT(_,cat::rest)) = countbooks(cat) + countcatalogs(rest);
```

Comment: hmm unbound value indetifier: countbooks

Comment: This is because the definitions are mutually recursive. I edit the answer.

Comment: Constructor name expected. sorry for my little knowledge  but i do not fell this language yet.

Comment: You have to tell *where* the constructor is needed. Where the error is signaled? Exactly as I wrote it works in my Moscow ML.

Comment: What is `KISS`. Wasn't it `KIS` (with one S)?